# python issue in anagram script

Tags: python, anagram

Second modification to the script (changes made below)

Made the changes mentioned in the comments (renamed all to print_all, and added the excepetion, changed the code below to reflect the same)

However, execution still exits without any reason

Initial query:

The following is a script that tries to identify various anagrams of a word (as in the website: http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=suchindra&t=1000&a=n):

```
import sys
import itertools
import threading
from collections import defaultdict


words_dict = defaultdict(lambda: "")
def lower_and_nocrlf(s):
    return s.lower().strip()

def two_or_more(s):
    if len(s) >= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def get_perms(cur_iter):
    lst = []
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        try:
            lst.append("".join(cur_iter.next()))
        except:
            break
    return lst

def get_twordlist(z):
    lst1 = []
    lst2 = []
    for i in range (1, len(z)):
        lst1.append(z[:i])
        lst2.append(z[i:])

    return lst1, lst2

def filter_dict(x):
    if x in words_dict.keys():
        return x
    else:
        return 0

def main():
    print_all = None
    word = None

    try:
        word = sys.argv[1]
        print_all = sys.argv[2]
    except:
        pass

    if word == None:
        try:
            word = sys.stdin.readline()
            print_all = sys.stdin.readline()
        except:
            pass

    if word == None:
        sys.exit(1)

    fd = open('/usr/apps/words', 'r')

    words = fd.readlines()

    fd.close()

    words_lower = map(lower_and_nocrlf, words)
    words_lower = filter(two_or_more, words_lower)
    from collections import defaultdict
    for i in words_lower:
        words_dict[i] = ""

    iter = itertools.permutations(word)

    all_permutations = []

    iters = []
    for i in range(0, 100):
        iters.append(iter)

    result = map(get_perms, iters)

    main_list = []
    for l in result:
        if l != []:
            for word in l:
                main_list.append(word)

    results = []
    try:
        main_list_len = len(main_list)
        for index in range(0, main_list_len):
            percent = (index/len(main_list)) * 100
            lst1, lst2 = get_twordlist(main_list[index])
            result1 = map(filter_dict, lst1)
            result2 = map(filter_dict, lst2)
            for index in range(0, len(result1)):
                if (result1[index] != 0) and (result2[index] != 0):
                    results.append("%s %s" % (result1[index], result2[index]))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("User stopped execution, partial results:")
        print results
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception:
            # catches all other types of exception here
        print(sys.exc_info())
            traceback.print_exc()

    print(results)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: BTW, `all` is **not** a good choice for a variable name as it shadows the built-in `all()` function. Also, you can use the built-in `exit()` function rather than `sys.exit()` (assuming you actually need an exit function...).

Comment: `s/results.append[result]/results.append(result)/`

Comment: @PM2Ring Moreover, `all` is not referenced in the rest of the program...

Comment: Thanks @gboffi. That was the first mistake. Now I don't know what else has gone wrong. I have modified the query and updated the code. I guess the filter(filter_dict, lst1, lst2) is wrong

Comment: @gboffi: Sure, so it won't cause a problem, but it's still not a good idea, and it's a bit confusing to other people reading the code.

Comment: I can follow your code up to the loop that builds the `results` list, but I cannot understand what you are trying to do with `get_twowordlist` and `filter_dict`, except that it is possibly wrong.

Comment: @gboffi, I wanted to do something like http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=suchindra&t=1000&a=n

Comment: I am just splitting the anagrams to two lists and seeing if they are proper dictionary words. If they are, then they should be printed as in the link

Comment: Modified the code in initial comment to the latest one

Comment: Thx all for suggestions. Issue is resolved (reflected in the final edit of the code in the initial commit). However, the speed is very less. Might have to use iterators to get this faster though

Answer (score 1):

So, your code is clearly executing down to the `print index` line and then failing somewhere inside the block. The exception handler only catches exceptions of type `KeyboardInterrupt` - i.e. when a user presses Ctl+C on their keyboard. Any other error will exit via the sys.exit(0) method, so you have no way of knowing what the error is.

Personally I quite like the `traceback` module for these printing out errors, so I suggest you modify your try catch block to be something like:

```
import traceback

try:
    main_list_len = len(main_list)
    print main_list_len
    for index in range(0, main_list_len):
        print index
        percent = (index/len(main_list)) * 100
        lst1, lst2 = get_twordlist(main_list[index])
        result = map(filter_dict, lst1, lst2)
        results.append[result]
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("User stopped execution, partial results:")
    print("Exception: %s" % (sys.exc_info()))
    print results
except Exception:
    # catches all other types of exception here
    traceback.print_exc()
```

This will allow you to debug the problem as the traceback module will give you line numbers and an error message to work with.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx all. Finally ended up identifying the culprit after a few hours. It is results.append[result]. It should have been results.append(result).

Comment: I still feel it should have continued the for loop, as it has nothing related to result being manipulated

Answer (score 0):

OK after some analysis, it looks like filter does not accept more than one list. The second issue is because I am using multiple lists in the filter